# Why does role management not work on my ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, .net, roleprovider

I have a web application in ASP.NET, which has a site map.

One of these menu items must be displayed only, if the user is assigned role `roleX`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
    <siteMapNode url="~/" title="Root"  description="...">
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Menu 1"  description="" roles="*">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Item 1"  description=""  roles="*"/>
        <siteMapNode url="~/rss.aspx" title="Subscription"  description="" roles="*" />        
      </siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="~/specialPage.aspx" 
                   title="Some special page" 
                   description="" 
                   roles="roleX"/>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

In my `web.config` I've setup the site map and the role provider like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MY-MACHINE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

...

<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
            description="Default SiteMap provider."
            type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider "
            siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
            securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
    </providers>
</siteMap>

<roleManager 
    defaultProvider="SqlProvider" 
    enabled="true"
    cacheRolesInCookie="false"
    cookieName=".ASPROLES"
    cookieTimeout="30"
    cookiePath="/"
    cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
    cookieProtection="All">
<providers>
    <clear/>
    <add
        name="SqlProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
        connectionStringName="dbConnectionString" 
        applicationName="MyApp" />
</providers>
</roleManager>
```

There are tables

1. `aspnet_Applications`
2. `aspnet_Membership`
3. `aspnet_Paths`
4. `aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers`
5. `aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser`
6. `aspnet_Profile`
7. `aspnet_Roles`
8. `aspnet_SchemaVersions`
9. `aspnet_Users`
10. `aspnet_UsersInRoles`
11. `aspnet_WebEvent_Events`

in the database `MyDatabase`.

There are no records in the `aspnet_UsersInRoles` table.

So, when I launch the web application, the menu item (site map node) `specialPage.aspx` should not be visible (because no user is assigne the role `roleX`).

But it is displayed nevertheless.

2 questions:

1. Why?
2. What can I do in order for the menu item `specialPage.aspx` to be visible only, if the user is assigned the role `roleX` ?

Comment: To start trouble shooting, I would suggest programatically testing if roles are working via: if(User.IsInRole("Role")) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127603(v=vs.110).aspx) in you code behind. Write some simple code that makes a control visible or not depending on the users role.

Comment: Next step would be to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495605/asp-net-web-sitemap-roles-do-not-seem-to-control-visibility and this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1096023.aspx?Treeview+with+Sitemap+hiding+node+based+on+roles