# Role Authorization in Azure WebApp

Tags: azure-web-roles, azure-webapps

I'm very new in Azure.  I built an Azure WebApp which my vendors and customers log into.  When users log in, they go to the SiteMap page.  I want customers only see and access certain pages in the SiteMap and the vendors see and access some other pages.  How can I do that in Azure?

Thanks so much!

Cheers,
Alan

Comment: .netframework  or core 3.1 ? You need to clarify your problem before we can give you a solution.

Comment: Hi Jason, I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough.  My web app is on WebForms .netframework 4.6.  Thanks!

Comment: This question should be a simple question, you can refer to this post first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495605/asp-net-web-sitemap-roles-do-not-seem-to-control-visibility

Comment: If the content of this post is what you need, I will sort out the answers and let more users in the forum refer to it.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Does my comment have any enlightenment for you? If you have a better solution, you can send out your answer, which can help more forum users.